# Why should I set a private function argument?

Tags: typescript

I have come across this type of function more than once.

```
myFunc(private myArg1: number) {
doing.awesome.stuff();
}
```

Now I understand OOP programming and I've came across private classes, methods and variables but this is the first time I came across a private function argument.

I would like to learn some more about why this is necessary, who can see this argument - or why it should be private, maybe it's basic TS scoping that I don't understand.

Comment: its meaningless, private in that context means nothing

Comment: This kind of arguments only make sense in constructors, where they automatically become private fields of the object. Are you sure you are not confusing anything?

Comment: That only does anything for a constructor argument, where it becomes a [parameter property](https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties).

Comment: Yes it is in the constructor, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`private` as argument used only in constructor

```
class Demo {
  constructor (private var1) { // VALID
    console.log(this.var1)
  }
  method (private var: number) { // NOT VALID
    console.log(var)
  }
  private method1 () { // VALID
    console.log('a')
  }
}
```

Take a look at this

```
class Demo {
  constructor (private var1) {
    console.log(this.var1)
  }
}
```

Same as

```
class Demo {
  var1: any = null
  constructor (var1) {
    this.var1 = var1
    console.log(this.var1)
  }
}
```

Just shorter